# Updating the Parent ID of Email Message. Working in Classic but not in lightning

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, email, apex-email-service

Hi we have created a custom code for updating parent id of `EmailMessage` it is working in the classic but has error when we switch to lightning. Error we receive is

> Operation is not allowed

Trigger:

```
trigger emailTrigger on EmailMessage (before update) {

    if(trigger.isbefore){
        if(trigger.isUpdate){
            EmailTriggerHandler.attachEmail(trigger.New, trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Triggerhandler:

```
public class emailTriggerHandler {

    public static void attachEmail(List<EmailMessage> emailRecList, Map<Id, EmailMessage> emailRecListOldMap){
        Map<Id, Id> mapIdtoClone = new Map<Id, Id>();
        Set<Id> parentCase = new Set<Id>();
        for(EmailMessage emailRec :emailRecList){
            if(emailRec != null){
                mapIdtoClone.put(emailRec.Id, emailRec.Transfer_to_Case__c );
                parentCase.add(emailRec.ParentId);  
            }
        }

        List<Case> caseRecList = [SELECT Id, Attach_Email__c FROM Case WHERE Id IN: parentCase];
        List<EmailMessage> emailRectListNew = new List<EmailMessage>();
        for(EmailMessage emailRec :emailRecList){
            for(Case caseRec : caseRecList){
                if(emailRec.Extract__c){
                    EmailMessage emailRecNew = new EmailMessage();
                    emailRecNew.ParentId = emailRec.Transfer_to_Case__c;
                    caseRec.Attach_Email__c = TRUE;
                    emailRectListNew.add(emailRecNew);
                }
            }
        }
        system.debug('try' + emailRectListNew);
        insert emailRectListNew;
        update caseRecList;
    }
}
```